# httpWebRequest/HttpWebReponse C# - WebView

Tags: c#, windows, webview, windows-phone-8.1

I developed a Windows Phone 8.1 app, problem is when I try a HttpWebRequest/ httpWebReponse on youtube.com, it brings me a Exception: `PayementRequired`.

Then I tried to circumvent the problem, so I decided to access the page with WebView and then extract the HTML Content by `InvokeAsync` method

```
("eval", new IEnumerable <string> ()     {"document.documentElement.outerHTML.toString ();"})
```

but I find that HTML is the WebView without Javascript code, if there is a way to enable javascript support in its WebView, Would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient instead of System.Net.Http.HttpClient.